# Pseudocode for date function definition

Tags: c++, c++11

Pseudocode I recieved:

```
Date& operator++(){
    //add 1 to d  //tomorrow, unless we were at the end of the month
    //if is_date is false
    //            //need to change to first of next month
    //  set d to 1
    //  if m is December
    //            //need to change to next year too      
    //    set m to January
    //    increment y
    //  else
    //    increment m
    return *this;
```

}

My Interpretation:

```
Date& Date::operator++(){ 
    if (is_date==false){ 
        m=m+1; 
        d=1; 
    } 
    if (m==dec && d==29){ 
        m=jan; 
        y=y+1; 
    } 
    else{ 
        m=m+1; 
    } 
    d=d+1; 
}
```

Does this look ok? I'm doing a hw assignment based off of Stroustrups book. Just needed some verification

Comment: Why not test it and see?

Comment: Pretty sure December has 31 days.

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly it seems that you can never reach the dates December 30th and December 31st as you roll over to a January in the next year if you the date is December 29th (and immediately jump to January 30th as the day will still be incremented).

Answer (score 1):

Let's increment `2010-03-10`:

```
    if (is_date==false){ 
        m=m+1; 
        d=1; 
    }
```

We assume `is_date` is true, so no action happens.

```
    if (m==dec && d==29){ 
        m=jan; 
        y=y+1; 
    }
```

`m` is not dec and `d` is not 29, so no action happens.

```
    else{ 
        m=m+1; 
    }
```

Wait! `m` is incremented.

```
    d=d+1;
```

So is `d`.

We have `2010-04-11` now - not what we wanted.

Look again at the pseudocode - the first thing that happens is adding a day. Everything else **only** happens if is_date is false. But is_date should not be interpreted as some static value, but instead should be implemented as a check if the date is valid (e.g. we have the 32. day after the incrementation). 
Only if the new date isn't valid the month and/or year are incremented.